# Querying multiple collections in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I've been working with Firebase for a little while, and like their suggestion to keep data denormalized. My only problem is figuring out the best way to query across multiple collections. For example, I have an Identity object which holds info on my users:

```
identities: {
  $identity: {
    name: string,
    studio: $studioID
}}
```

That corresponds to a Studio object:

```
studios: {
  $studio: {
    name: string,
    owner: $identityID,
    location: $locationID
}}
```

This object references the owner, and also their location. The location object references Classes, which references Students.... on and on. Right now, in order to fetch a referenced object, I'm doing something like this:

```
Auth.loginUser(email, password, (success) => {
    const identityRef = firebase.database().ref('/identity');
    identityRef.child(success.uid).on("value", function(identitySnapshot) {

      const identity = identitySnapshot.val();
      const studioRef = firebase.database().ref('/studios');

      dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_IDENTITY', identity})

      studioRef.child(identity.studioID).on("value", function(studioSnapshot) {

        const studio = studioSnapshot.val();

        dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_STUDIO', studio});
    })}); });
```

I would continue nesting my calls for Location, Classes, Students, etc. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following structures:

```
identities: {
    $identityKey: {
        name: string
    }
}

identities_studios: {
    $identityKey: {
        $studioKey: {
            name: string
        }
    }
}

identities_studios_locations: {
    $identityKey: {
        $studioKey: {
            $locationKey: {
                lat: string,
                lng: string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first, `identities`, only stores info about the identities as usual.

The second, `identities_studios`, only stores info about the studios, but the studios are grouped by `$identityKey`.

The third, `identities_studios_locations`, only stores info about the locations, but they are grouped firstly by `$studioKey` and secondly by `$identityKey`.

Now you can do this:

```
const db = firebase.database()

Auth.loginUser(email, password, success => {
    db.ref(`/identities/${success.uid}`).on("value", snap => { ... }

    db.ref(`/identities_studios/${success.uid}`).on("value", snap => { ... }

    db.ref(`/identities_studios_locations/${success.uid}`).on("value", snap => { ... }
}
```

Instead of making multiple requests one after the other, we get them to run simultaneously.

If you want, after getting all this info from the database, you can transform the data structure to whatever you want: one array for identities, another for studios, another for locations, etc.; or a single array of identities with nested studios which in turn have nested locations etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! The only issue I have is that my data is still tethered together, even though it is in different "collections." Since everything is bound to that particular uid, how would I share the same data with multiple users? My reason for breaking things into different collections is to make it available to multiple entities.